# Show nearest locations(market, bus stand etc) of the search result(s) on Gmap Drupal 6

Tags: google-maps, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am using view(style:map) to show search result on Gmap. It works fine but i need to show **nearest locations(market, bus stand etc) of the search result(s)**. How do I do that?

it is fine if I will get nearest locations(market, bus stand etc) on the search result(s) by **clicking a button or something else**. Please help.